# Updating AWS Security Group Rule via PHP SDK 3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-security-group

I am using PHP SDK v3 the latest release. The documentation for this does not contain an example and the validation is confusing. I am using the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifySecurityGroupRules.html).

I am trying the following:

```
$result = $ec2Client->modifySecurityGroupRules(
    [
    'GroupId' => 'sg-ebd1cf8e',
    'SecurityGroupRules' => [
        'SecurityGroupRuleId' => [SECURITY GROUP ID],
        'SecurityGroupRule' => [
            'SecurityGroupRuleId' => [SECURITY GROUP ID],
            'CidrIpv4'            => [NEW IP4 ADDRESS],
            'Description'         => [RULE DESCRIPTION]
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
print_r( $result );
```

response:

```
Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the ModifySecurityGroupRules operation:
[SecurityGroupRules][SecurityGroupRuleId] must be an associative array. Found string(21) XXXXXXXXXX in /var/www/XXXXXXXXXX/aws/Aws/Api/Validator.php:65
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#modifysecuritygrouprules), the Security Group Rule Id is a string, but that validation is looking for an associative array, which is never defined.

Comment: It's complaining about the value being the wrong type,  and you have totally removed any value type information from your question, and made your string values look like arrays, so it's impossible to point out what your error is. Looking at the PHP documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#modifysecuritygrouprules here, the second `SecurityGroupRuleId` should be  `ReferencedGroupId` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to @mark-b
Better [documents are here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#modifysecuritygrouprules) to the ones i was using.
Here's my code that worked:

```
$result = $ec2Client->modifySecurityGroupRules( [ 
    'GroupId' => '<group id>',
    'SecurityGroupRules' => [
        [
            'SecurityGroupRule' => [
                'CidrIpv4'          => '<ip address>/32',
                'CidrIpv6'          => '',
                'Description'       => '<description>',
                'FromPort'          => -1,
                'IpProtocol'        => -1,
                'PrefixListId'      => '',
                'ReferencedGroupId' => '',
                'ToPort'            => -1,
            ],
            'SecurityGroupRuleId' => '<rule id>',
        ]
    ]
]);
print_r( $result );
```